Maximize the volume of a cylinder, bounded on the outside by a roughly cylindrical point cloud. C++
I am receiving a point cloud from a 3d scanner system which has already had outliers filtered. It is roughly cylindrical and an example looks like this:
Front view
Isometric view
I need to create a C++ algorithm that will maximize a cylinder bounded on the outside by this pointcloud.
It needs to be relatively fast (less than 1 second runtime) but doesn't have to be perfect.
I have tried using the pcl library to fit a cylinder to the pointcloud which looks interesting and I am able to generate a cylinder then resize it so it fits within the bounds but I would then need to expand it as it is only bound on the outside by one point.
pcl::SACSegmentationFromNormals<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> seg;
seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
seg.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_CYLINDER);
seg.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);

Could I expand this cylinder generated by pcl until it is fully constrained by multiple points or is there a better way to do this problem.

I have also looked a library called ALGLIB that has some interesting features but I am not sure what the best method to use would be for the library.

Find the axis of your cylinder and the point with the smallest distance to that axis?

You could take a look at how PCL optimizes the cylinder coefficients: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/sample_consensus/src/sac_model_cylinder.cpp#L42 (here optimizing means using Levenberg-Marquardt to minimize the sum of all point-model distances). You could adapt this, e.g. by giving a higher penalty if a point is inside the cylinder than if it is outside, and perhaps add 1/radius to maximize the radius?
